# How to translate a request from overpass turbo format to a raw request and make it work?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

## Reason to ask: unexpected change in behavior between working overpass turbo request and a request made using Python to the API

I need to get an outline of a region bases off its name and import it into geopandas

This request works in overpass turbo ([link to results](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1vxy)):

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Велижский район}}[type="boundary"]->.a;
(
    relation["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="6"](area.a);
);

(
  way(r);
  node(w);
);
out skel qt;
```

This [request](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1vxB) also works:

```
[out:json];
relation(3342303)[type="boundary"];
out geom;
```

I can then download them into GeoJSON and plot the results using geopandas:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file('export.geojson')
df.geometry = df.geometry.to_crs(epsg=32636)
df.plot()
```

## What I have tried

```py
import overpass

api = overpass.API()

query = """
relation(3342303)[type="boundary"];
out geom;
"""
res = api.Get(query)
```

## What I expected

To get back a json

## What happened

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownOverpassError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-2eef0e720784> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 out geom;
      8 """
----> 9 res = api.Get(query)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/overpass/api.py in _as_geojson(self, elements)
    212                             polygons.append([points])
    213                         else:
--> 214                             raise UnknownOverpassError("Received corrupt data from Overpass (incomplete polygon).")
    215                 # Then get the inner polygons
    216                 for member in elem.get("members", []):

UnknownOverpassError: Received corrupt data from Overpass (incomplete polygon).
```

### update 1

I was able to get something to Python, but this does not solve it as these lines have in total zero area:

```py
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon

def extract_geometries(element, geometries):
    if 'members' in element:
        members = element['members']
        for member in members:
            if member['type'] == 'way' and 'geometry' in member:
                geometry = member['geometry']
                coordinates = [(point['lon'], point['lat']) for point in geometry]
                line = LineString(coordinates)
                geometries.append(line)
            elif member['type'] == 'relation':
                extract_geometries(member, geometries)

def close_polygon(geometry):
    if geometry.geom_type == 'Polygon':
        coordinates = list(geometry.exterior.coords)
        if coordinates[0] != coordinates[-1]:
            coordinates.append(coordinates[0])
            return Polygon(coordinates)
    return geometry

def get_relation_geometry(relation_id):
    # Define the Overpass API URL
    url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"

    # Define the Overpass query for the relation ID
    query = f"""
    [out:json];
    rel({relation_id});
    out geom;
    """

    # Send the GET request to the Overpass API
    response = requests.get(url, params={"data": query})

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Convert the response to GeoPandas dataframe
        data = response.json()

        # Extract the 'elements' list
        elements = data['elements']

        # Create an empty list to store geometries
        geometries = []

        # Iterate over the elements and extract geometries
        for element in elements:
            extract_geometries(element, geometries)

        # Create a GeoPandas dataframe from the geometries
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geometries)

        # Forcefully close the polygons
        gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(close_polygon)

        return gdf
    else:
        print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
        return None

# Example usage
relation_id = 3342303
gdf = get_relation_geometry(relation_id)
if gdf is not None:
    print(gdf.head())
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to get something to python, but lines are somehow do not create a positive area polygon

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify `[out:json];` in your request. The default [output format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_format_(out:)) is XML. This is likely the reason why the parser's `_as_geojson()` thinks that it received "corrupt data".

Comment: When I add  [out:json]; , I get an error ```query = """
[out:json];

relation(3342303)[type="boundary"];
out geom;
"""
res = api.Get(query)```

```OverpassSyntaxError: [out:json];
[out:json];

relation(3342303)[type="boundary"];
out geom;out body;```, My understanding that overpass package added this row by default.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.
Well, then maybe this is a bug in the overpass python package? The returned data from Overpass API is valid JSON. However, not valid *Geo*JSON, since `[out:json];` returns JSON, *not* GeoJSON. If this package expects *Geo*JSON then there must be a conversion somewhere in between. Could be caused the following outstanding issue: https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/issues/135